# How can I change the amount of data copied back into RAM when resuming in Linux?

Tags: linux, hibernate, swap, swappiness

Normally when I shut down my computer I hibernate. On the next boot I then resume. My problem is, that it seems that Linux just copies the least amount of data that is needed back into ram, because when I'm switching between applications there's a small delay until these are usable because they still have to be loaded from disk (which is an HDD in my case, which makes this delay quite noticeable).

Is there a parameter which determines how much data is copied back into RAM by the kernel after resume? Is it possible, that the [`swappiness`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) does affect that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux doesn't keep track of what clean pages were in RAM when the system hibernates. They're just discarded because they can be loaded back from disk. So when the system resumes, it has no idea what to load, other than what absolutely needs to be loaded. Your applications have to fault back in the pages of their executable files.